# Update sql query using CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, case

In the below query, when @test is 0, it is updating the values to null. Is there any way to retain the old value when the @test is 0? (There shouldn't be any update if @test is 0)

```
declare @test bigint

set @test=12

update teacher set dta=(case when @test!=0 then @test end) from teacher
```

Comment: Why you need to use `CASE` expression while you can check the condition one time before running the UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good opportunity for a conditional update:

```
Declare @test bigint = 12

IF @test <> 0 UPDATE teacher set dta = @test from teacher
```

Note that this will change all values in the dta column of the teacher table.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try by **WHERE** Clause

```
DECLARE @test BIGINT

SET @test=12

UPDATE TEACHER SET DTA=@test FROM teacher 
WHERE @test!=0
```